# Memory allocation to a Node with Character array in a Linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

OK, this is a simple single linked list program in c

```
struct node
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int sem;

    struct node *link;
};

typedef struct node* Node;

Node getnode()
{
    Node temp=(Node)(malloc(sizeof(Node)));
    if(temp==NULL)
        printf("\n Out of memory");

    return temp;
}

Node ins_pos(Node first)
{
    Node temp=getnode();
    printf("\n Enter id ");
    scanf("%d",&temp->id);
    printf("\n Enter name ");
    scanf("%s",temp->name);
    printf("\n Enter semester ");
    scanf("%d",&temp->sem);

    if(first == NULL)
    {
        temp->link=NULL;
        return temp;
    }

    else
    {
        int pos,i;
        printf("\n Enter position: ");
        scanf("%d",&pos);

        if(pos == 1)
        {
            temp->link=first;
            return temp;
        }

        else
        {
            Node prev=NULL,cur=first;
            for(i=1; i<pos; i++)
            {
                 if(cur==NULL)
                    break;

                prev=cur;
                cur=cur->link;


            }

            if(cur==NULL && i < pos)
                printf("\n Position invalid");
            else
            {
                prev->link=temp;
                temp->link=cur;
            }

            return first;
        }
    }
}

Node del(Node first)
{
    if(first==NULL)
        printf("\n List is Empty ");
    else
    {
        Node temp=first;
        printf("\n ID: %d was deleted",temp->id);
        first=first->link;
        free(temp);
    }
    return first;
}

void disply(Node first)
{
    if(first==NULL)
        printf("\n List is empty");
    else
    {
        Node cur=first;
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
            printf("\n ID : ");
            printf("%d",cur->id);
            printf("\n Name : ");
            printf("%s",cur->name);
            printf("\n Semester : ");
            printf("%d",cur->sem);
            printf("\n\n\n");

            cur=cur->link;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    Node first=NULL;
    int opt;

    do
    {
            printf("\n QUEUE MENU\n 1.Insert at position  \n 2.delete front\n 3.display\n 4.Exit \n\n Enter your choice : ");
            scanf("%d",&opt);

            switch(opt)
            {
                case 1 :first = ins_pos(first);
                        break;

                case 2 :first = del(first);
                        break;

                case 3 :disply(first);
                        break;

            }


    }while(opt!=4);


    return 0;
}
```

When inserting a new node, Code Blocks Crashes at the malloc statement. How do I know? well, it crashes before asking "Enter ID". So, am I doing something wrong?

Another point here is, it works fine with only an integer field in node, the problem here maybe the character array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function `Node getnode()` -

```
Node temp=(Node)(malloc(sizeof(Node)));
```

With the above `malloc` you allocate memory equal to size of `Node` which is of type struct pointer , and is not enough .Therefore ,you get a segmentation fault.

instead of this ,write like this -

```
Node temp=malloc(sizeof(*temp));        //also there is no need of cast
```

This will allocate memory equal to size of type to which `temp` points to i.e size equal to that of structure. Which is appropriate .

Comment: I noticed this answer doesn't explain *why* this fixes the problem.

Comment: @immibis I have added the explanation . If you see any problem ,please feel free to point it out . Thanks !! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some errors here.

```
 malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
```

Otherwise too little memory is allocated.

Do you include `stdlib.h` for malloc definition - that would cause this issue (no definition, defaults to int).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Node temp=(Node)(malloc(sizeof(*temp)));`

Comment: Sorry, oversight. Corrected.